# How can I replace a special character with an onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, onclick, special-characters

I found a Js function for collapsible text.

```
    function toggle(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);

      if (e.style.display == '')
        e.style.display = 'none';
      else
        e.style.display = '';
    }

    </script>
```

And here is the html :

► Title01 
     
    Text01, Text01, Text01, Text01, Text01, Text01, Text01, Text01, Text01,

What I would like is when I onclick this special character : `&#9658;` it would change in this one :`&#9650;` , any clues ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Change the clicked link content. innerHtml will solve your issue.

Comment: Hello could you be more specific, please. I am very visual :S

Comment: wrap the special char into e.g.  `<span id="note1-toggle">&#9658;</span>` that way you can find to by your `id` and change it with `innerHTML`.

Comment: @t.niese was clear enough already.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! Alright I did put it in a span but ( Sorry I'm a bit new ) What about the innerHtml ? Would you mind showing me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

wrap the speacial html character `&#9658;` with a `<span>` tag:

```
<a onClick="toggle(this, 'node1')"><span>&#9658;</span> Title01 </a>
```

then you can change it to `&#9650;` after showing the hidden element and back to `&#9658;` when it's hidden:

```
function toggle(elm, id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id),
      a = elm.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];


  if (e.style.display == 'none')
  {
    e.style.display = '';
    a.innerHTML = '&#9650;';
  }
  else
  {
    e.style.display = 'none';
    a.innerHTML = '&#9658;';
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/X5W6S/)

Comment: You are missing the brackets around your if and else statements, but honestly why repeat the same line twice in the first place? If it is in the if and else why have it within the if at all.

Comment: in addition to JoshMein if you suggest to use a library like `jquery` you should mention this. additionally if it is jquery  `$(this).innerHTML` would not work, because `$(this)` is an jquery object and not an `HTMLElement` and therefore has not attribute `innerHTML` you could use.

Comment: t.niese makes a good point. You did not even mention that your code used a library which most likely the OP would not realize either and your code would not work. Also you should really describe your code as the OP will just paste it in to their project and not learn what it really does.

Comment: i know i posted the answer too quickly before testing it, sorry for that. it should work fine now and there's no need for jquery.